# prove that $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} f(t) g(Nt) \, dt = \int_{0}^{1} f(t) \, dt \int_{0}^{1} g(t) \, dt $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

> Let be $f,g$ continous, periodic real fuctions on $ \mathbb{R} $. How can I show that
>
> $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f(t) g(Nt) \, dt = \int_0^1 f(t) \,dt \int_0^1 g(t) \, dt $$

So you can rewrite:

$$ \int_0^1 f(t) g(Nt) \, dt = \sum_{j=1}^N \int_{ \frac{j-1}{N}}^{\frac{j}{N}} f(t) g(Nt) \, dt $$

This leads to

$$ \lim_{ N \rightarrow  \infty} \int_0^1 f(t) g(Nt) \, dt = \lim_{ N \rightarrow  \infty} \sum_{j=1}^N \int_{ \frac{j-1}{N}}^{\frac{j}{N}} f(t) g(Nt) \, dt $$

By the mean value theorem for the integration there exists a $ \xi_j  \in \big[ \frac{j-1}{N} , \frac{j}{N}\big]$ so that

$$ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^N f( \xi )  \int_{ \frac{j-1}{N}}^{\frac{j}{N}} g(Nt) \, dt. $$

How can I continue If I want to prove that statement with the mean value theorem?   (Change of variables and use of Riemann sums)
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Surely you mean "$g(Nt)$" and not "$g(NT)$" in all of the integrals on the left sides?

Comment: upsi yes ! I'll edit it

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ $1$-periodic?

Comment: @SangchulLee yes, they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $\xi_{N,j} \in [\frac{j-1}{N}, \frac{j}{N}]$ such that

$$ \int_{\frac{j-1}{N}}^{\frac{j}{N}} f(t)g(Nt) \, \mathrm{d}t
= f(\xi_{N,j}) \int_{\frac{j-1}{N}}^{\frac{j}{N}} g(Nt) \, \mathrm{d}t
= f(\xi_{N,j}) \frac{1}{N} \int_{0}^{1} g(u) \, \mathrm{d}u, $$

where we utilized the substitution $t = \frac{j-1+u}{N}$ as well as the $1$-periodicity of $g$. Then

$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(t)g(Nt) \, \mathrm{d}t
= \underbrace{\left( \sum_{j=1}^{N} f(\xi_{N,j}) \frac{1}{N} \right)}_{(*)} \int_{0}^{1} g(u) \, \mathrm{d}u $$

Then you can employ your favorite argument to show that the *Riemann sum* $\text{(*)}$ approximates the integral $\int_{0}^{1} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$ to conclude.

Comment: thank you for your answere! i have one more question..I can't explain myself why $ (*)$ approximates the Integral $ \in_0^1 f(t) dt. is this a property of riemann sums?

Comment: @wondering1123, Yes, indeed. The sum $\text{(*)}$ is a bona-fide Riemann sum for the integral $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$. Since the mesh size of the partition, which is $N^{-1}$, converges to $0$, the corresponding Riemann should converge to the integral.

Comment: Since $\xi_{N,j}\in\left[\frac{j-1}{N},\frac{j}{N}\right]$ the Riemann sum   $N^{-1}\sum^{N}_{j=1}f(\xi_{N,j})$ is converging to $\int^{1}_{0}f(t)dt$, for a continuous function indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Make the change of variables $u=Nt$ to get
$$\sum^N_{j=1}f(\xi_j)\frac{1}{N}\int^{j-1}_jg(u)\,du=\Big(\int^1_0g\Big)\sum^N_{j=1}f(\xi_j)\frac{1}{N}\rightarrow\Big(\int^1_0g\Big)\Big(\int^1_0f\Big)$$